# Commutator property

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can you please show me how to prove this? If H,K,L are normal subgroups of G then $$[[H,K],L]\subseteq [[K,L],H][[L,H],K]$$ Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hints (**Care**: you need to know well commutators identities) By normality we have

$$[[H,K],L]=[H,L][K,L]\;,\;\;[[K,L],H]=[K,H][L,H]\;,\;\;[[L,H],K]=[L,K][H,K]$$

So you want to show

$$[H,L][K,L]\le[K,H][L,H][L,K][H,K] =[H,L][K,L]^{[H,K]}$$

Answer (score 0):

i took an element from the first and show that it is contained in $$H\cap K\cap L$$ but the second is contained in $$K\cap L$$.is it ok?

Comment: Make it as an comment to @Don's leading answer, if you want him to have a looking at it.